# Joomla - designating a function to home page when it is built in the template without module

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm building a site  with a slider on top. It appears on all the pages, and built straight in the template (no module / component).
How can I restrict it to the home page only?

http://www.joomla24.com/remository/Download/Templates_for_Joomla_3.x/1%29_General_Joomla_3.x_Templates/DD-Medicine_RX.html

Answer (score 0):

For the definitive method, see http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page

I generally set a variable at the top of the template, like this:

```
$home_page = $menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault();
```

Then I can use that variable in conditionals anywhere on the page I like:

```
if ($home_page) {
  echo 'Home page only';
} else {
  echo 'Not the home page';
}
```